# Firebase events export from BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, analytics, data-export

Is there a recommended way of exporting firebase events to Google Cloud Storage (for example Parquet format)?
If I export my data to BigQuery, what is the best way to have the data consistently pushed to GCP Cloud Storage?

The reason is that I have daraproc jobs dealing with parquet files in Cloud Storage, I want my firebase data to be accessible in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting data from BigQuery directly as parquet file is not supported currently.
BigQuery supports three format now,

- CSV
- Avro
- JSON

You have option to transform data to parquet file using Apache Beam & Google Cloud Dataflow. Use ParquetIO to transform data after reading data from BigQuery and write it to Cloud Storage.

#### Reference

Exporting Data(BigQuery)
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types

ParquetIO(Apache Beam)
https://beam.pache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/parquet/ParquetIO.html